# Saving a sql file after creating a Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

Visual Studio wants me to save a sql file `dbo.Table.sql` after I create a Controller for the model that represents the table in my database. The tutorials and documentation that I find online do not mention this at all.

- http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_models.asp
- http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/generating-views

So it opens up a safe dialogue after I specified the Model and Context and press `add` on the `Add Controller` dialogue. The path starts in my Documents folder but I am not sure where to safe this, I would logically place this in `App_Data`.

- So why does it ask me to safe the sql file?
- And where do I need to store it?
- And perhaps, why is this not mentioned in the documentation? I'm pretty sure I am doing it in the same manner. Create SQL Server -> Add tables -> Add Model -> Add MVC5 Controller with views using Entity Framework

[image]

Comment: That's because VS doesn't do anything of the kind. You probably created a *SQL script file* instead of a database by mistake,eg from New File. The generators create and add any files to the project directly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have a `DataBase.mdf` file in my `App_Data` folder. I created this by `new item` -> `SQL Server Database`. Have done it yesterday and it wasn't asking me to save such a file at all.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, I had a typo in my Model class so it did not find the table, you can see it in the screenshot. If you ask me it would be better to throw a warning when adding a controller that does not have a correctly mapped table and give the option to create a local script file for it. On the other hand, now I know this it's probably obvious.